# Keyboard not working on boot

Tags: 12.04, usb, mouse

I have read other related threads, but none quite seem like this. I upgrade to 12.04 today and every time I boot, the keyboard stops working. It works in grub and bios, but as soon as I am to the login screen, the keyboard looks like it isn't even running with the numlock key not lit up. The only way to fix this is to unplug and replug the keyboard. It is a USB keyboard, though I also have a separate USB mouse that works fine.

Comment: Same here. Random keyboard and mouse failures (both wireless and on the same receiver, connected to usb).

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot into recovery mode and run dpkg

Comment: Unfortunately, this has not fixed it after all. My keyboard is still being dropped, not just at boot. It is being dropped at random times throughout the whole time Ubuntu is running.